# Menus do not respond to mouse clicks in logmein or advanced system care on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

The menus in LogMeIn respond to the first mouse click.  After that it won't respond unless I close and then reopen the Logmein menu.  There is a similar problem when I run Advanced System Care.  The main menu options along the top will work but it will not respond to clicks any where else in the menus.  The mouse works as expected with all other programs.  I am running Windows XP SP3.